# Window in Spark Streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

In spark streaming, the DStreams we receive is a batch of RDDs. So how does windowing helps further.

As per my understanding it also batches the RDDs.

Correct me if I am wrong (new to Spark Streaming).

Comment: TD explains it in detail here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spark-users/GQoxJHAAtX4.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The number of records in one batch is determined by the batch interval. A window will keep the number of batches as fit within the size of a window, that's why the window size must be a multiple of the batch interval. Your operations will then run on multiple batches, and with each new batch the window will move forward, discarding older batches.

The point is that in streaming, data that belongs together doesn't necessarily arrive at the same time, especially at low batch intervals. With windows you are essentially looking back in time.

But note that your job still runs at the specified batch interval, so it will produce output at the same pace as before but look at more data at once. You will also look at the same data multiple times!

There a nice blog post by Michael Noll which explains this in more detail: http://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2013/01/18/implementing-real-time-trending-topics-in-storm/.

Update:

You can increase your batch interval, but then your job is processing slower as well, i.e. only creating output every 10 seconds instead of 2. You can also put a window on one part of the computation, whereas the batch interval affects everything. Check out `reduceByKeyAndWindow` for example.

Comment: Thanks for an higher view of window and batch i.e sometimes you need a time frame wherein you need to process the data.

Comment: Say my batch interval is of 2 Seconds , it contains 3 RDDS and my window frame is of 10 seconds that means i have 15 RDDS at once to process ...rite? Why can't i just increase my batch size?

Comment: @MariusSoutier If you apply windowing to a DStream does it affect any subsequent operations? For instance, suppose I converted the DStream into PairStream with windowing. Does the operations involving the new PairStream uses windowing?

Answer (score 5):

*Batch Interval:*

•   Streaming computations -> Continuous series of batch computations -> Acted on small batches of data

•   Spark Steaming -> Receives data from several sources -> Groups it into small batches -> new batch are created at regular time intervals

•   Beginning of each time interval -> new batch is created -> any data that arrives during the interval gets added to the batch.

•   Each input batch forms an RDD

*Window Duration* : Combines results from multiple batches
*Sliding Duration* : Controls how frequently the new DStream computes results

Example 1: Source DStream of Batch Interval = 10 sec wanted to create a Sliding window of last 30 sec (or last 3 batches) -> Window Duration is 30 sec

The sliding duration, which defaults to the batch interval, controls how frequently the new DStream computes results.

Example 2: If we had the source DStream with a batch interval of 10 seconds and wanted to compute our window only on every second batch, we would set our sliding interval to 20 seconds

Answer (score 0):

So the window allows you to sample data from the stream based on (in my experience) number of milliseconds specified for the window and the increment.

My work to date has been consuming from Kafka topics, so I set my window as follows:

```
LOG.info(metricTagType+"::Grouping by Key & Window:["+windowDuration+"]  Increment:["+windowIncrement+"]...defn.");
Duration winDuration = new Duration(windowDuration);
Duration incrementDuration = new Duration(windowIncrement);
JavaPairDStream<String, Iterable<String>> grpedJpd = jpd.groupByKeyAndWindow(winDuration, incrementDuration);
```

What I found out with trial and error, was that the windowing will not work properly if you do not use the above; to do a separate groupBy and then a window does not give the desired results.

One final thing, in case, the window increment must be a multiple of the duration in the following when getting a context, otherwise spark throws an exception:

```
JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf,
                                        Durations.seconds(duration));
```